# How to implement function that is the inverse of push?

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a function that is the inverse of push : it retrieves the
value stored in a linked-list's head node, then removes that node from the linked list.

Parameter head points to the first node in a linked list.

I'm trying to make the function copy the value in the list's head node to the location pointed to by parameter popped_value, then unlink the head node from the list and return a pointer to the first node in the modified list.

This is the code I have so far. I'm really stuck on this, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
typedef struct intnode {
  int value;
  struct intnode *next;
  } intnode_t;


intnode_t *pop(intnode_t *head, int *popped_value) {

assert(head!=NULL);

head = head->next;

popped_value=&head->value;


free(head);

return head;

}
```

Comment: The word you are searching for is "Pop."

Comment: You don't describe the problem, but what are you expecting with `head = head->next; popped_value = &head->value`? And why `free(head);` before returning `head`?

Comment: I was trying to store the next node value into the head node and then store this value into the location pointed to by popped_value.

Answer (score 0):

The program you show seems to be a 'shift', real 'pop' is described below the 'shift'.

Shift: you want to return a pointer to the next item (not the current head), and set `popped_value` to the current head value

```
intnode_t *shift(intnode_t *head, int *popped_value) {
   assert(head!=NULL);
   // get next pointer here, since 'head' cannot be used after it's been freed
   intnode_t *next = head->next;
   // sets the int variable which pointer is given as argument to
   // the current head value
   *popped_value = head->value; 
   // you can now free head without worries
   free(head);
   // and return the next element (becoming the new head)
   return next;
}
```

To be called, for instance, as

```
int myvalue;
intnode_t *newhead = shift(head, &myvalue);
```

Note that this operation is usually named **shift** since you take the first item value from the list, and remove that element. **pop** is usually when you take (to set `popped_value` to it) the *last* item value, then remove that last element.

That *pop* would be something like

```
intnode_t *pop(intnode_t *head, int *popped_value) {
   assert(head!=NULL);
   intnode_t *last,*previous;
   // get last and last's previous element
   for(previous=NULL,last=head ; last->next ; last=last->next) previous=last;
   // get the last value
   *popped_value = last->value; 
   // free last element
   free(last);
   // If at least two elements, tell the previous one there is no more 
   if (previous) previous->next = NULL; // previous is last now
   // return the head or NULL if there no more element
   // (previous is NULL if there was only one element, initially)
   return previous ? head : NULL;
}
```

This algorithm assumes the last element has its `next` pointer set to `NULL`. The return value will either be `head` again (head to the list) or `NULL` if the list had only one element to tell the caller the list has no more element alive.

You call 'pop' this way

```
int myvalue;
// head had to be declared and initialized before
head = pop(head, &myvalue);
if ( ! head) { // no more element
   break; // for instance, depending on your program
}
```

---

Since you are a student, here is a recursive version of *pop* that does the same thing

```
intnode_t *recpop(intnode_t *this, int *popped_value) {
    if (this->next) {
        // this is not the last element
        intnode_t *next = recpop(this->next, popped_value);
        // next element was the last
        if ( ! next) this->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        // this is the last element
        *popped_value = this->value;
        free(this);
        this = NULL;
    }
    return this;
}
```

for your study.